# Get data from Database Using Ajax and PHP and Return Result as Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the idea of what i wanted but need assistance on how to get it done.Below is the scenerio: I have a two dropdwon. The First dropdown is fetched from the DB, which works fine. At the change event of the first dropdown,the system should go to the Database, and fetch the result into the next dropdown. see what I have done so far for assistance:
JQUERY SECTION

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/scripts/newJquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#locate").change(function(){
       var selectedloc = $("#locate option:selected").val();
       $.ajax({type: "POST",url:"process-loc.php",data:{loca:selectedloc}}).done(function(data){
            var ans=jQuery.parse(data);
           //using php-mysql before
           var ps = ans.res;
           $("#subloc").html(ps);

       });
    });
    });
    </script>
```

FrontEnd(HTML)

```
 <tr>
    <th>Primary Location:</th>
    <?php 
   $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tab_location");?>
    <td>
    <select name="locate" class="form-control" id="locate">
    <option>Select Main Location</option>
    <?php while($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rw['location_name'];?>"><?php echo $rw['location_name'];?></option>
      <?php };?>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Sub Location:</th>
    <td id="subloc"></td>
  </tr>
```

Process-loc.php

```
if(isset($_POST["loca"])){
        include 'includes/session.php';
        include 'includes/db_connection.php';
        include 'includes/functions.php';


        $main = $_POST["loca"];


         $gets = "SELECT * FROM tab_fltlocation WHERE mainloc='".$main."'";
         $get = mysqli_query($connection,$gets);
         $gt = mysqli_fetch_array($get);


         //$nos= $gt['opsNo'];


          if(mysqli_num_rows($get)>=0)
          {
          echo json_encode(array("res"=>$gt));//or do a dropdown using <select name='subloc'><option value=$gt['loc']>$gt['loc']</option></select>
          }else{
          echo json_encode(array("res"=>"0"));
          }

       }
         ?>
```

This is what I wants to be displayed on the Front End page for the use:
$gt['loc']
How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query   = "
                SELECT 
                    tariff_name
                FROM tariff_setting";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->_connection, $query);

       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            $response[] = $row['tariff_name'];
       }

$tarrifList = json_encode($response);
```

// $tarrifList is the response and sent it in json encode format and decode on ajax success

// Javascript Process

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(resdata);
    var areaOption = "<option value=''>Select State</option>";
     for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
         areaOption += '<option value="' + obj[i] + '">' + obj[i] + '</option>'
     }
     $("#patientSelectState").html(areaOption);
```

Comment: $tarrifList is send as the response of the ajax call

Comment: if its not working, please send me the response of "var ps = ans.res; console.log(ps) in the ajax response.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your AJAX processor to do this:

**Process-loc.php**

```
/* Above code the same */
if(mysqli_num_rows($get)>=0) {
    $out = '<select id="selSubLoc"><option value="">Choose One:</option>';
    foreach($gt AS $loc){
        $seld = ($_POST['loca'] == $loc) ' selected' ? : '' ;
        $out .= '<option value="' .$loc. '" ' .$seld. '>' .$loc. '</option>';
    }
    $out .= '</select>';
}else{
    $out = 0;
}

echo $out;
```

And change your front-end code's AJAX routine to be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     url:"process-loc.php",
    data:{loca:selectedloc}
}).done(function(recd){
    $("#subloc").html(recd);
});
```

The data received back from PHP will be in HTML format unless you use `dataType:` to change it, so you can build the HTML over on the PHP side and then just plop it into the `#subloc` table cell.

Comment: It works, I just had to change it to suit my desire, but your response was 100% ok.

Answer (score 0):

On the event of the first box call the function containing the ajax which would retrieve information from the database. This ajax call will get data according to the first input.
Now query your database and echo the results in a foreach loop(you can make a tag there only). 
In the ajax 'success:' catch the data and display it.

```
//from the database
foreach ($info as $product) 
{
echo "<option value=".$product['childsticker_id'].">".$product['name']</option>";
}

      //ajax call page
      success: function(result) 
      {
        $("#states").html(result);
      }
```

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html